# Nokia backup on a Mac

Tags: mac, backup, sync, sms

As I have to bring my phone to a shop for repair, I want to backup my contacts, calenders and text-messages. My Nokia connects perfectly through Bluetooth with iSync. One baddy, however is that text-messages are nowhere to be found or for the matter of fact, impossible to backup from the phone using iSync. Is there a graceful, free application for Mac that would be able to backup (and later restore) the messages on my phone?

The worst possible scenario would include me to write a script that uses the Hayes command set and kermit-ize all SMS's (hundreds at least), so a nice click-and-play solution would be nice to know about. I don't consider applications like Parallel/CrossOver as a solution, as PC Suite is quite buggy with those (which does have the functionality to backup SMS and e-mail).